# Introduction to Heidegger

Tags: ontology, phenomenology, heidegger, being-and-time, introduction-to-philosophy

I have not read anything of Martin Heidegger and I am interested in starting. I understand that "Being and Time" can be very difficult, so what would be a good place to start? (including books by others).

Comment: Maybe [The Routledge Philosophy Guidebook to Heidegger and Being and Time](https://books.google.it/books?id=DZXfG0bQhvMC&pg=PR1).

Comment: Could you give some of your background. Are you familiar with Husserl's phenomenology, for example, Nietzsche, Hegel, German romantics? To get Heidegger you need to understand the context of his writing, both philosophical and historical, his works are full of obscure allusions, poetic and self-made language, etc. The best way might be to start not even with the secondary sources (commentary) but tertiary, like Friedman's Parting of the Ways or Wolin's Heidegger's Children. In original sources go first for short essays, like What is Metaphysics or Letter on Humanism, not Being and Time.

Comment: Useful background material perhaps:  the early Catholic influence, note studied Scholasticism which would mean an all important engagement also with Aristotle https://www.google.com/amp/philosophy.avemaria.edu/post/37187209894/heidegger-and-catholicism-some-very-introductory/amp ; good points made in here:  IEP https://www.iep.utm.edu/heidegge/ ; Heideggerian Terminology:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heideggerian_terminology

Comment: @Conifold I am familiar with Nietzsche, and I have a general knowledge of German Romanticism but mainly from the criticism of Isaiah Berlin. Hegel, I have never read. I understand the basics of Phenomenology but have never read Husserl.

Comment: There is a story that shortly before his death Heidegger read a book by Dr. Suzuki and commented 'This is what I've been trying to say in all my writing'. So perhaps Suzuki and Zen might usefully shed some light on H's philosophy. It certainly needs a lot of light shed on it. I find him very difficult but would recommend his Introduction to Metaphysics. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your support. Since I posted this question, I read Being and Time with a tutor where we went in-depth on practically every page. It was a revelation that led me to read other books by Heidegger and incorporate them into my thinking. For others interested, I can share my own experience whereby I would not have been able to understand much without the help of [Michael Millerman](https://g.co/kgs/oPcD7t) who tutored me through this process.

Mr White's answer above is very helpful also. I have read the Irrational Man which is an excellent book on the whole spectrum of Existential philosophy of which Heidegger is perhaps the most important part. So that you for this Mr White.